# Liquibase diff command filtering

Tags: liquibase

I develop liquibase extension for diff command. When i analyze code, i saw that liquibase compare all objects. And those objects contains filtered(diffIncludeObjects) objects. Liquibase only use filter property while showing results. I think it is not good design. Do you have any idea? Why do they use this design?

Comment: It is difficult to answer this question, as it would be primarily opinion based. What about the design do you think is not good? Do you have ideas for how to make it better?

Comment: Ty for quick response. I want to develop extension for data compare. In example: I need to compare 15 of 100 tables. Other tables not neccessary for me. I wrote data comparator but it compare all 100 tables. So it is lost of time. When compare metada, it is not problem. But you compare data, it is problem.

Comment: I see. I don't fully understand why Liquibase was designed the way that it was, but I am fairly certain that it was not designed with doing data comparisons as a primary feature. As with all software design, there are tradeoffs that need to be made. Since the primary use case is schema management, it is likely easier to get correct answers for complex schema differences if the code takes all objects into account (when calculating dependencies, etc.) I can see where this causes problems in your use case. I don't know the Liquibase architecture well enough to suggest an alternative approach.

Comment: If you have a suggestions for a feature, I kindly ask you to submit and issue in github or add a PR to the liquibase project.  We could even host your extension if it aligns with what the community needs.  Check it out: https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues
Is that helps, could you close this question out and continue the conversation with the Liquibase team?

Comment: Forgot to mention there is a developer channel on Liqubase's Discord server, you could also use: https://discord.gg/9yBwMtj